# Show notification on events in title bar also for question pages

Tags: feature-request, notifications

If you are on tag question page, you are able to see the activity (new questions on that tag or edit in some of current questions on page) on title bar of the tab. This would be really nice to have also on question pages.

For example, I am often reading some documentation or code from external resources in other tabs to answer the question and meanwhile someone already has posted the correct answer, or the author has edited the question to be quite different. This is really frustrating since it may take quite long to find the right spot and when you finally are ready to answer the question, you find out the notification on that page saying *1 new answer to this question* and someone already answered it.

Since the detection already exists for such activities, couldn't the title be updated too?

I was surprised that I didn't find this already, so keep an eye out for detecting it as a duplicate still.

Comment: I agree with you, many times I find someone else has written the same thing I was about to. To alleviate that issue I keep updating the page as I work on the answer but it is rather troublesome.

Comment: Even worse is when the question gets closed.

Comment: Big Meta Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227820/show-new-activity-in-the-page-title Sadly it was incorrectly closed.